# asp.net button inside a datalist to go to another webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need the button inside the datalist to open another page. However the response.redirect does not work !

here is the html

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">

<div id="content">
    <!-- Review -->
    <div class="products">
        <h3>My Books</h3>
        <h4>Items you have purchased</h4>
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="618px" Height="114px">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="bookid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("BookID") %>' Visible=" false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="bookname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="review" runat="server" Text="Review" CommandName="review" />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

below is the cs file

```
public void DataList1_ItemCommand(Object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "review")
    {
        DataList1.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        Label bookid = (Label)DataList1.SelectedItem.FindControl("Bookid");
        Response.Redirect("Review.aspx");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to attach **ItemCommand** event to **DataList1**.

```
<asp:DataList OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" ...>
      ...
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Server.Transfer("Review.aspx", true);`